# Выделить грамматическую основу

Tags: синтаксис, однородные-члены

Пожалуйста, определите грамматическую основу в предложении!

> *Из комнаты вышла не Мария, а Анна и короткими шажками пошла по коридору.*

Здесь получается два однородных подлежащих (*Мария*, *Анна*) и два однородных сказуемых (*вышла* и *пошла*)? Или *не Мария, а Анна* целиком одно подлежащее? Спасибо.

Comment: Если какой-либо ответ вам помог, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

Грамматическая основа: Мария, Анна — подлежащие; вышла, пошла — сказуемое.

Однородные подлежащие могут соединяться союзами, что в данном предложении и можно наблюдать.

Comment: Большое спасибо. А по поводу "вышла"? Получается, здесь и однородные сказуемые "вышла и пошла".

Comment: @Marina конечно! простите, я пропустил этот глагол.